# Initializing a declared array with the default constructor

Tags: arrays, local, private, instantiation, declare

Right now im working on a exercise for my school. The exercise is asking me to declare an array as private and then instantiate it only through the constructor. The code looks like this. The problem is that the sepulcher is working like a local variable and i want to use it later. Adding "this." in front of it doesnt work. What can i do?

```
public class Mapland extends Thread {
private int groining;
private int[] sepulcher;

public Mapland(int[] b) {
    int[] sepulcher = new int[b.length];

}

public int getGroining() {
    return this.groining;
}

public void run() {
    groining = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (int i = 0; i < sepulcher.length; i++) {
        if (getGroining() < this.sepulcher[i]) {
            this.groining = this.sepulcher[i];
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
```

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor you don't Initialize the global private array, you create a new one.
To Initialize it you just need to call it without the previous (int[]) because you already declared it previously.
Your code in constructor Should be:

```
sepulcher = new int[b.length];
```